# Return false then an item can't be added to a has_many with :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-relations

I have this models relations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trip_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :trips, through: :trip_memberships, uniq: true
end

class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trip_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, through: :trip_memberships, source: :user, uniq: true
end

class TripMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I add some user as a trip member, like with this code:

```
trip = Trip.last
john = User.last
trip.members # => []  Empty right now
trip.members << john
trip.members # => [john]  Contains John
trip.members << john
trip.members # => [john]  Contains only John, but...
TripMembership.all # => [TripMembership(trip, john), TripMembership(trip, john)]
                   # There is 2 memberships, even the accessor methods only show one
                   # member because of the :uniq option
```

I don't want to have duplicates in the `trip_memberships` table, but I want to follow the "Tell, don't ask" principle. I don't want to check if a given record exists.

I added this validations to the TripMembership model

```
class TripMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :trip_id, :user_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :trip_id, scope: [:user_id]
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: [:trip_id]
end
```

I expected the `<<` or `concat` method to return false when I try to add a record that can't
be saved, like in the has many relations, but seems that with `through` relations it don't works that way.

```
trip.members << john # => ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Trip has already been taken, User has already been taken
```

Anyone knows an elegant way to archieve this? I think that the api should be used like this.

```
if @trip.members << new_member
   flash[:success] = "new member added"
else
   flash[:error] = "can't add this member to trip"
end
```

Comment: I tend to avoid direct array manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had an idea.

Since I've just discovered that the standard behavior of rails is to raise an exception if the user is not a new record, and I must not change the default behavior of a well-known methods, I'll extend my association with a custom method called `add_member` that just alias calls `<<` inside a begin/rescue.

```
has_many :members, through: :trip_memberships, source: :user, uniq: true do
  def add(*records)
    self.<< records
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    false
  end
end
```

I have my own method that works as expected without changing the rails methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:

```
 if @trip.members.include?(new_member)
    flash[:error] = "Member already exists"
 else
    @trip.members << new_member
    flash[:success] = "new member added"
 end
```

**Edit**

```
has_many :members, through: :trip_memberships, source: :user do
  def <<(member)
    if self.include?(member)
      false
    else
      super(Array(member)-self)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Of course I could, but my goal is to just add the records, without asking asking for inclusion. I've just had an idea.

Comment: You can't do without checking. But you can implement `<<` do your job by overriding it. See my edit.